# PHP PEAR error Class 'XML_Serializer' not found?

Tags: php, xml, xml-serialization, pear

I need to turn an array into an XML file.
I have the following code:

```
<?php
$nouser = 'There is no user with that ID in the database.';
try {
$handler = new PDO('sqlite:Ebsco.db');
$handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$name = '';
if (isset ($_POST['postname'])) {
    $name = $_POST['postname'];
};

$query = $handler->query('SELEcT * FROM Users WHERE ID='.$name);
$User = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
if ($User) {

    $Serializer = &new XML_Serializer();
    $XML = $Serializer->serialize($User);
    print_r($XML);
print_r($Serializer);
}
else {
    echo $nouser;
}
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $nouser;
    die();
}
?>
```

The code works fine for retrieving the array and passing it back to the html as an array, but I am having issues with the PEAR XML_SERIALIZER.
I have downloaded the files and placed them in the php/pear/xml folder (except for "package" which I left in the main pear folder, as I have no idea what it is meant to do), and checked the phpinfo() to make sure the include_path leads to php/pear.
However, when I add the XML_SERIALIZER, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'XML_Serializer' not found in...
```

I am new to PEAR so I'm not sure if I installed everything correctly (other than putting the files in the library, is there anything else I need to do?), or if this is caused by another issue.
Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the file manually, there is no autoloading with PEAR1 packages except you do that yourself.

```
require_once 'XML/Serializer.php';
```